# Can we use the UniDynArray at the place of DB2DynArray

Tags: db2

I am using the DB2 V11 in which the DB2DynArray is not present.
I the classes are looks same they are providing same type of features. SO can I use this and will be supportive with UniSubroutine.

Comment: Have you compared the classes? Have you contacted the vendors for support and advice?

Comment: Yes I have compair the classes.